# How to create an excel function that outputs the content of a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an excel function that concatenates the text contained within a range of cells C4:K9.

Although the code below concatenates the text within the range of cells, I am not successful in inserting a carriage return (vbCrLF) between each row. So when I type the function in the cell I wish to see the output value, I want it to be contents of C4:K4, carriage return, C5:K5, carriage return, and so forth until C9:K9 all in one cell.

```
Function Join(rng As Range, delimiter As String) As String
Dim cell As Range, rowIndex As Long
 For rowIndex = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
   For Each cell in rng(cells(rowIndex,3), cells(rowIndex,11))
    Join = Join & cell.Text & delimiter
   Next cell
   Join = Left(Join, Len(Join) - Len(delimiter)) & vbCrLF
 Next rowIndex
End Function
```

Does anybody have any ideas as to how to make this function work?

Comment: Try modifying the line `For Each cell in rng(cells(rowIndex,3), cells(rowIndex,11))` to `For Each cell In rng.Rows(rowIndex).Cells` and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to loop over each cell in a row, you can do it by this: `For Each cell In rng.Rows(rowIndex).Cells`.

To show multiple lines within a cell, you need `vbLf` as last character of each line (and "Wrap Text" as cell format).

```
Function Join(rng As Range, delimiter As String) As String
    Dim cell As Range, rowIndex As Long
    For rowIndex = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For Each cell In rng.Rows(rowIndex).Cells
            Join = Join & cell.Text & delimiter
        Next cell
        Join = Left(Join, Len(Join) - Len(delimiter)) & vbLf
    Next rowIndex
End Function
```

One last hint: Please try to avoid internal VBA names (Join, RowIndex) for your own function names or variables.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will try to keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the `For Each cell` line of your code to make it work:

```
Function Join(rng As Range, delimiter As String) As String
Dim cell As Range, rowIndex As Long
 For rowIndex = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
   For Each cell In Range(rng(rowIndex, 1), rng(rowIndex, rng.Columns.Count))
    Join = Join & cell.Text & delimiter
   Next cell
   Join = Left(Join, Len(Join) - Len(delimiter)) & vbCrLf
 Next rowIndex
End Function
```

To understand the difference... I started with your line:

```
For Each cell in rng(cells(rowIndex,3), cells(rowIndex,11))
```

-The problem is we're using a fresh `Range` - it's a subset of `rng` but it's fresh, so:

```
For Each cell In Range(rng(rowIndex, 1), rng(rowIndex, 9))
```

-That works fine, but then to make it more dynamic I swapped the 9 for a column count:

```
For Each cell In Range(rng(rowIndex, 1), rng(rowIndex, rng.Columns.Count))
```

Comment: Thank you for a thorough explanation of the difference! I will try this

Answer (score 0):

You have misaddressed the source cells with `rowIndex = 1`. Try this:

```
Function Join(rng As Range, delimiter As String) As String
    Dim cell As Range, rowIndex As Long, colIndex As Long

    For rowIndex = rng.Row To rng.Row + rng.Rows.Count - 1
        For colIndex = rng.Column To rng.Column + rng.Columns.Count - 1
            Join = Join & Cells(rowIndex, colIndex).Text & delimiter
        Next
        Join = Left(Join, Len(Join) - Len(delimiter)) & vbCrLf
    Next rowIndex
    Join = Left(Join, Len(Join) - 1)  ' cut terminal crlf
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! Still in the process of trying!